# Use orange juice instead of water for syrup to make Orangettes?

Tags: candy, water, juice, syrup, oranges

I used [this serious eats recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2012/01/orangettes-recipe-how-to-make-chocolate-orange.html) to make orangettes. After removing the oranges from the syrup in the end I further reduced it in order not to waste it. After tasting I though it could do with a bit more orange flavour and wondered:

- Could I just squeeze the peeled oranges and use their juice instead of part or all the water in the syrup to make the leftover syrup taste stronger of orange?
- Would this affect the Orangettes? How?

I'd also be interested in suggestions as to how I can use my syrup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting the peel simmer in the syrup is to candy the peels, as they are too bitter to be eaten as is. In my opinion, adding orange juice to this syrup won't make that big of a difference. The peels in themselves has a much stronger orange flavor than the juice has. If it makes you happy, you can replace some of the water with juice. When not wanting to waste, I just eat the oranges.

As to the syrup, I understand you do not like to waste stuff, but it is just water and some sugar (with some extra flavor now), so I usually discard it. However, if you really wanted to, you could use it in several applications, but make sure you account for the correct ratio (orange sauce for a duck breast, maybe you could add it to a cake if the water is no problem, you could make turkish delight with it, etc.)

Comment: Hey @Mien, thanks for the answer and some suggestions. I edited my question to clarify that my goal is to have more orange flavour in the leftover syrup without negatively affecting the Orangettes. Would that work through using juice? – This time I also just ate the oranges :)

Comment: Hmmm, I *think* using juice will help, however that does not have a really strong flavor. You could use some of the water in which you first boiled the peels in. That will have an orangy flavor, but might also have some bitterness, but should be balanced out due to the sugar in the syrup. No real idea :) Also, interesting for you as it should also work with orange peels: http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/03/how-to-make-fresh-lemon-syrup.html